# iPhone retina display UITableview issues

Tags: iphone, uitableview, retina-display

[image]

on clicking red circular button When delete button appears , It pushes cell content view to left. I want content view to keep on its place.

Suggest me ways to achieve this task.

Comment: sorry for the full image. I forgot to crop it.

Comment: Sorry your OP is clear know, I deleted my answer

Comment: I appreciate your answer either because I didn't know my simulator was zoomed.  I've just updated x-code to version 5.2. This piece of code is working fine in ios version 5.1 (3.5 standard resolution) but when I run this on simulator with 3.5 retina display running ios 7 then this problem occur. I guess it is due to Higher operating system. But I want to know the solution which can help me in both higher and lower os versions.

Comment: Yeah.... It would be the same on non-retina simulator in iOS7, you could try it. See my new answer. I'm happy that I did help you with my old answer anyway :))

Answer (score 1):

This is how `UITableViewCell`s are designed in iOS7. They push the content view aside. I'm not sure if there is a built-in way to avoid this. I would bet not, it's how apple acts sometimes :(

One possible solution would be to reproduce the iOS7 tableViewCell. You would need to build an subclass of `UITableViewCell` and implement the slide to delete functionallity manually. You can create a custom protocol or call the UITableViewDelegate protocol. But you would have to set you tableViewDelegate as the delegate of the single cell.

The guys of teehan+lax did that as iOS7 was still under NDA. They build the complete look and feel for iOS6 or less: [teehan+lax blog post](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/reproducing-the-ios-7-mail-apps-interface/)

I hope this is a possible solution and the post will help you!

Comment: COOOOl!! That means I have to roll up my sleeves and get back to code to achieve this.

Comment: I actually fell in love with custom tableViewCells. They can be SO helpful! Please keep me up to date how your work is going and if you have success with it!

Comment: sure , why not I'll definitely share

Comment: Please read and try my second answer. This should work. I didn't remember this delegate method as I wrote this answer. I'm sorry if you already did waste time with the reproduction process :/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if you ran into complicated reproduction process. The tableViewDelegate does actually give you a method for this:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

`[cell setShouldIndentWhileEditing:NO];` could also work.